# ORACLE Send Email using SSL

Tags: oracle, ssl, plsql, email

is it possible to send e-mail over ssl in plsql?
thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Not with pure PL/SQL afaik. We added some java classes to the database which performs the SSL mail sending with the java mail api.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle's UTL_SMTP does not support SMTPS (SMTP over SSL) - you have to wrap the connection.  See [this link for a working, but not recommended for production use, example.](http://monkeyonoracle.blogspot.com/2009/11/plsql-and-gmail-or-utlsmtp-with-ssl.html)